# How do I connect to MySQL from Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have MySQL installed in the `/usr/local/bin/`. I need to be able to connect to the MySQL database, however, the mySQL gem cannot connect to my database, and it seems that it is looking for the database in the `/opt` folder.

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts about this:

1. Have you checked if MySQL is actually running? In most linux environments this can be done on the command line by executing `"/etc/init.d/mysql status"` or simply connecting to the database with the command line client.
2. I think your configuration should point to `"localhost"` when running on the same machine and is then using either sockets or tcp connections to connect to the database, so the `/opt` folder message you posted seems weird.

Please provide more information.

Comment: I went ahead and removed ruby and rails from the /opt/local/ directory and instead installed it in /usr/bin/ folder. everything works fine now. Thanks.